# TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, image, typeerror, google-colaboratory, zip

I am trying to save the new cropped brain tumor images into the subfolders of TRAIN_CROP, TEST_CROP, and VAL_CROP in the main folder of TRAIN, TEST, and VAL.  x_set and y_set each contains the images which  I want to separate in 'YES' and 'NO'.

````
def save_new_images(x_set, y_set, folder_name):
    i = 0
    for (img, imclass) in zip(x_set, y_set):  <---showing error here
        if imclass == 0:
            cv2.imwrite(folder_name+'NO/'+str(i)+'.jpg', img)
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(folder_name+'YES/'+str(i)+'.jpg', img)
        i += 1
># saving new images to the folder
!mkdir TRAIN_CROP TEST_CROP VAL_CROP TRAIN_CROP/YES TRAIN_CROP/NO TEST_CROP/YES TEST_CROP/NO VAL_CROP/YES VAL_CROP/NO

save_new_images(X_train_crop, y_train, folder_name='TRAIN_CROP/')
save_new_images(X_val_crop, y_val, folder_name='VAL_CROP/')
save_new_images(X_test_crop, y_test, folder_name='TEST_CROP/')```
````

Comment: Looks like you redefined `zip` to be a `ZipFile` object earlier

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, the case is solved by writing

```
from zipfile import ZipFile as zipfile
```

Actually the `ZipFile` is the module within `zipfile` class.

Comment: Or just import ' from zipfile import ZipFile'

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem.

A common cause is that you have reassigned the variable zip to another value via a statement like:

`with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip`.

Therefore your zip variable is now an instance of ZipFile class and not the zip class.

To solve this issue, simply reassign the ZipFile call to some other value

`with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zips`

That should work

P.s if you're using google colabs you might have to restart your runtime after making the change

Answer (score -1):

This means that you somehow shadow the `zip` builtin with `ZipFile`.

One possible reason would be that you have an import like:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile as zip
```

In that case use a different alias.

Another possibility would be that you do a *-import (`from somemodule import *`) which does the same.